# How to signin for multiple contracts at the same time?

Tags: nearprotocol

The JS SDK authenticates a wallet by way of `requestSignIn()`, however, this function takes only a single contract id, and I want the frontend app to hit multiple contracts on behalf of the user.

I suppose I could make it such that all transactions go through a single funnel contract, but this isn't really scalable - what if I want a dApp that also hits contracts outside my control?

What's the advice to solve this? I guess I could make the user signin multiple times, but that's pretty awful..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a prefix for each private key being stored which would let you login to as many contracts as you want.

It's just a string prefix used to namespace the user's private key once they "login" (once they add a `FunctionCall` access key)

https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-api-js/blob/ffe12359f94aa8b558824a3f3ec1f4ba82c0e86a/login-advanced.html#L19

Comment: Thank you, but there is still a single contract being specified here: https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-api-js/blob/ffe12359f94aa8b558824a3f3ec1f4ba82c0e86a/login-advanced.html#L35

Comment: sure -- all that function does is add a NEAR `FunctionCall` access key to your browser's `LocalStorage`.   this key is used to sign transactions when you call a function.  as long as you have the access key then you can target as many contracts as you like

Comment: right, but to get the access key for different contracts wouldn't you then need to call requestSignIn() for each separate contractId?

Comment: yes, you can call `requestSignIn` multiple times or you can build up your own transaction with several `AddKey` actions and sign once